# How can I stop code from running from a button on another form?

Tags: .net, winforms, vb.net-2010

I've written a program that loops through a list from a DB, sets up some tables in the DB, and prints out a PDF of a Crystal Report.  While it's printing, I have a new window pop up that has a label saying what is currently printing and a button to Cancel the job.  The problem I'm having is that while the reports are gathering data and printing the report, the pop-up is un-responsive and the cancel button usually doesn't do anything.  Sometimes I get luck and time it right so my code gets called, but I have to jam on the button.

I thought maybe threading was the answer, but I haven't found a solution that works using that.  I have a few DoEvents scattered about, but that's not really the answer, I know.

Just wondering if anyone might have a solution.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Look on the BackgroundWorker http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: Why do you have another window pop up?

Comment: You might be able to just print in a task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend putting your printing job in another thread.

Display a window popup (modal form) when you program is ready to print. Inside this window popup ([OnLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onload.aspx) method) start worker thread e.g using [BackGroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class and dismiss this dialog when printing finished or Cancel button is pressed.